Using TikZ to Plot the Fourier Transform with Magnitude and Argument Coloring
I would like to use TikZ to draw the function graph of the Fourier transform
() of ^ sin()(). The x-axis represents , the y-axis represents the magnitude of (), and different colors of curve are used to represent the argument of (). I do not want to use a data table to plot the graph. Additionally, I saw the usage of
point meta={TeX code={(math image)code(math image)}}

in the reference here to automatically calculate the color values, but I have not been able to get it to work successfully.
The magnitude of () is:
\frac{1}{4+\omega^4}

and the argument of it is:
\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2\omega}{2-\omega^2} \right)

